# How do I format as latex an element of an array into a title/label in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, matplotlib, latex

I have an array of numbers and I want its elements as the titles of subplots in a figure in Python. I want to format these titles in latex style.

I'm afraid this might be a simple question but I have not seen the answer elsewhere. I've seen that people use raw strings r'$ ... $' for latex expressions but I could not apply it successfully to solve this problem.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc

#LaTeX font
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True) 

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

#The numbers I want as titles for the subplots
Nums = [0.01,0.10,0.30,0.75,1.00,2.00,10.0,12.0]

nrows=2
ncols=4
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=4)

for row in range(nrows):
        for col in range(ncols):
                ax[row,col].set_title(repr(Nums[col+row*ncols]) + '$\\ \\mathrm{GeV}$')
                ax[row,col].plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

The best I managed to do is write the units in latex style and the numbers in "text" style. [This is how it looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pgPC1.png)

Comment: please append a screenshot to clarify your statement 'The best I managed to do is write the units in latex style and the numbers in "text" style.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you say about that?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import rc

#LaTeX font
rc('font',**{'family':'sans-serif','sans-serif':['Helvetica']})
rc('text', usetex=True) 

# Some example data to display
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 400)
y = np.sin(x ** 2)

#The numbers I want as titles for the subplots
Nums = [0.01,0.10,0.30,0.75,1.00,2.00,10.0,12.0]

nrows=2
ncols=4
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2,ncols=4)

for row in range(nrows):
        for col in range(ncols):
                #ax[row,col].set_title(repr(Nums[col+row*ncols]) + '$\\ \\mathrm{GeV}$')
                ax[row,col].set_title(r'${:.2f}\mathrm{{GeV}}$'.format(Nums[col+row*ncols]))
                ax[row,col].plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

giving you this output

[image]

In you solution you juste encoded the GeV part as laTex, while the number was encoded as plain test (not in dollars).

You find more info about the used format statement [here](https://pyformat.info).

Note: You should replace `Nums` with `nums`. Capitalized variables are used for classes. Read the [PEP8 Style](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions) guide for more info.